# Porquê o atributo com anotação @ManyToOne não aparece na resposta em json no Postman? Porquê tal atributo não é salvo quando é salva sua entidade?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, jpa, postman

Eu tenho uma classe chamada Equipe com um atributo chamado lider com a anotação @ManyToOne, porém quando chamo o endpoint da minha api para salvar uma equipe no postman o resultado em json não aparece o atributo lider. Na minha classe LiderService têm um método chamado insereEquipe que salva uma equipe, mas tal método aparenta não salvar o atributo lider e deixa nulo.

Porquê está acontecendo isso? esse metódo insereEquipe está correto? o que estou errando? Porquê o atributo lider não aparece na resposta em json no Postman?

Classe Lider:

```
@Entity
public class Lider {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lider_id")
    private List<Equipe> equipes = new ArrayList<>();
    .
    .
    .
```

Classe Equipe:

```
@Entity
public class Equipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String categoria;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Lider lider;
    .
    .
    .
```

Classe LiderService que têm o método insereEquipe:

```
@Service
public class LiderService {
     
     public Equipe insereEquipe(Long id, Equipe equipe){
        Lider lider = findById(id);
        equipe.setLider(lider);

        lider.getEquipes().add(equipe);
        equipe.setLider(lider);

        equipe = equipeRepository.save(equipe);

        return equipe;
    }
```

Classe LiderController:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/lider")
public class LiderController {

    @Autowired
    private LiderService service;

    @PostMapping(value = "/insere-equipe/{id}")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public ResponseEntity<Equipe> insereEquipe(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Equipe equipe){
        Equipe obj = service.insereEquipe(id, equipe);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
    }
```

Aqui o resultado quando chamo o endpoint http://localhost:8080/lider/insere-equipe/1 no Postman, repare que não retorna o atributo lider na resposta:
[Inserção da equipe TimeE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tnwJ.png)

Comment: o problema ai não é o manytoone, mas sim o fato de você ter anotado ela tb com jsonIgnore

Comment: Lucas Miranda o problema é que quando tiro a anotação @jsonignore, dá um erro no backend e nada funciona no postman, os get para listar todos lideres e todas equipes não funcionam...

Comment: esse erro ocorre pq você quer gerar um json a partir de um objeto que possui redundancia, a equipe tem um lider e no lider tem equipes e assim infinitamente, você precisa primeiramente corrigir essa sua linha de pensamento

Answer (score -1):

A anotação @JsonIgnore é comumente usada quando se deseja evitar a serialização recursiva ou ciclos infinitos de referências entre objetos. Nesse caso, como a classe Lider possui um relacionamento bidirecional com a classe Equipe (um líder pode ter várias equipes e uma equipe pertence a um líder), a inclusão do atributo lider na serialização de Equipe poderia causar um ciclo infinito de referências. Então, quando ele é anotado no atributo, a sua serialização é ignorada, por isso o atributo não é incluido ao Json resultante quando o objeto é convertido em Json. Tenta colocar o @JsonIgnore no atributo "List<'Equipe'> equipes" da classe Lider ao invés da classe Equipe.

Classe Lider
@Entity
public class Lider {

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lider_id")
    private List<Equipe> equipes = new ArrayList<>();
    .
    .
    .
```

Classe Equipe

```
@Entity
public class Equipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String categoria;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Lider lider;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).